# embedding code into MSP430 without JTAG

Tags: usb, embed, msp430, uart, jtag

I am a newbie in this subject and want to learn how to embed codes into MSP430.
I have a breakout board MSP430-H5438 and I am not using JTAG interface.
I have the IAR generated codes (hex files) ready (ADC, SPI interfaces), however I could not load them into the IC.
I am using a USB-UART bridge to connect device to PC, BSL scripter for software, but there is no result.
Is it a wrong way to connect MSP430 to PC without JTAG interface? Am I running in circles here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSL should work but you need to connect not only the TX and RX but also you need to have DTR connected to RST and RTS  to TEST. If your USB-UART interface only has TX and RX (which is often the case) then it will not work with BSL.

Note that the MCU on that board supports not only the regular (and expensive) JTAG but also the newer SBW interface. This means you can get the $4.30 Launcphad and program your board using the programmer that is included on the Launchpad. This will let you do anything you can do over the regular JTAG and is highly recommended over BSL since it will give you hardware debugging functionality. And the Launchpad can be useful on its own too.